# Packard Bell Easynote NJ65 not saving gamma Setup

Tags: 10.10, intel-graphics, bug-reporting

There seems to be a issue with the Easynote range of PB laptops. Since Ubuntu 10.10 does not use a Xorg.conf file to save your gamma / resolution /brightness setting, everytime I turn on my laptop I have to open up a terminal window and use the **x-gamma** command to set it up to my personal preference.

Is there a way to create a configuration file which can save that into the system everytime I load up the OS? When I used to have a Compaq Presario (an F564LA with integrated nVIDIA graphics), I could save a config. file into the system which loaded up everything on startup

To those who don't know the spec's for a NJ65 laptop, I'll provide them

- Processor: Intel® Pentium Dual Core @ 2.2 GHZ
- Video: Integrated Intel® GMA 4500MHD graphics
- HDD: 320GB SATA
- RAM: 2GB DDR2

Answer (score 2):

Boot into recovery root console thingy. Run:

```
X -configure
cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

reboot and you should now have an xorg.conf to configure :)